# PHP undefined variable , but print_r outputs the results to screen

Tags: php, debugging

Does any one have a clue what this issue might be ?

consider the following code:

```
127:  print_r($foo);
128:  if(isset($foo)){
129:   echo 'it has value';
130:  }else{
131:   echo 'foo is empty';
132:  }
```

the result printed to the browser screen is :

```
Array([key] => some value)
Notice: Undefined variable: foo in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 127
```

Yes , it says on the exact line number where it outputs the value that the very same 
variable is undefined ,

in the previous lines of code , I'm actually including a file where I'm defining the $foo variable.

So in further investigation I set an other print_r($foo); inside the include , where the variable was printed without a warning.

Any clues why is this happening , any workaround  ?

Comment: The warning is usually printed *before* the output. Your output is probably coming from somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

$foo is undefined. The output is coming from a line before 127.

Comment: but after commenting line 127
    127: // print_r($foo);
the output is gone !

Comment: @Antagonist Read my solution. You'll get your output

Comment: @Antagonist: PHP does not produce Notice errors simply for the amusement of producing them. It will *either* produce the notice *or* it will print the value recursively. It will *never* do both at the same time. The *only* logical reason you're getting output prior is something else before that is outputting an array, recursively. There's no arguing this fact. Without seeing more code, this is the only answer you'll get.

Comment: ok , but I cant paste the code here ... I'm developing a framework , a simple one , but there is a quite a lot of code ...

Answer (score 0):

You're getting warning message because `print_r($foo);` must be within `if(isset($foo)){...`. 
If you didn't define `$foo` before `print_r` there will be nothing to output.

Comment: I have defined it before ...
and id does have a value , double checked !

Comment: how about this : I'm defining that variable inside an Include file , when I changed the inlude_once statement into include ... the problem was solved !

Comment: If you want to fix warning message, just do what I wrote. You will not get any warning. Insert `print_r` into `if(isset...)`  Also post full code of your page for more detailed answer. Where did you defined `$foo` before?

Comment: Rememmber, You know your code more than everone else. We can help you ONLY if you post your code with all details. My solution works in all cases